# Setting Visibility on a Drawer Menu

Tags: android, jquery, xml, android-studio

I want my menu to display a sub-menu below it when the menu is clicked. I've tried several ways of doing that but I just can't make it work. The app crashes whenever I click the menu.

Here's my Java

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        MenuItem acc1 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.manage_profile);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.manage_profile) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery2) {
    }
    else if (id == R.id.search_school) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.school_vielnearby) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.school_vielall) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery3) {
    }
    else if (id == R.id.search_organization) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.organization_vielnearby) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.organization_vielall) {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here's my menu XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group
    android:id="@+id/menuall">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="My Account">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/manage_profile"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="      Manage Account">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery2"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="School">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_school"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="      Search School"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/school_vielnearby"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="      View Nearby"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/school_vielall"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="      View All"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_gallery3"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:title="Organization">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_organization"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="      Search Organization"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/organization_vielnearby"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="      View Nearby"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/organization_vielall"
        android:checked="false"
        android:visible="false"
        android:title="      View All"/>
</group>
</menu>
```

So basically I want my app to set the visibility to true when the menu is clicked.

Here's the logcat when I click a menu containing this code

```
if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        MenuItem acc1 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.manage_profile);
        acc1.setVisible(true);

    }

    01-01 20:20:52.696  21622-21622/ph.schoolar.schoolar W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41bf7c08)
01-01 20:20:52.706  21622-21622/ph.schoolar.schoolar E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ph.schoolar.schoolar, PID: 21622
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at ph.schoolar.schoolar.StudentView.onNavigationItemSelected(StudentView.java:114)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(NavigationView.java:150)
            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
            at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$1.onClick(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:308)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4654)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19438)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat output ?

Comment: done sir, please help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to find id.You have already `item` object from `onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

remove line

```
MenuItem acc1 = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.manage_profile);
```

try with

```
item.setVisible(false); //true or false
```

**for your requirement**
if you have used NavigationView

```
navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    for (int menuItemIndex = 0; menuItemIndex < menu.size(); menuItemIndex++) {
        MenuItem menuItem= menu.getItem(menuItemIndex);
        if(menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.search_school){
            menuItem.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok it works but my problem is still there. I typed in your code and when I click the menu if i set it to false the menu i clicked disappears, What i want to happen is when I click a certain menu other menu will show up

Comment: have you used `navigationView`?

Comment: here it is NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);